# SwiftUI: NavigationLink unintentionally tappable and activated inside Form

Tags: swift, forms, swiftui, navigationlink

I seem to have a problem where a `NavigationLink` is being reformatted in a `Form`. My `NavigationLink` is activated via `isActive` upon a button press that toggles `showNext`.

The problem is that the `NavigationLink` seems to be activated on its own even when the button doesn't exist by tapping the empty row which the `Form` seems to create for the `NavigationLink` which should just be an `EmptyView`. It seems like the `Form` creates rows even for `EmptyViews`.

So I was thinking there might be some possible solutions, but I'm not sure if these are possible:

(1) Somehow hide the row created for the `NavigationLink`/`EmptyView` completely without disabling the navigating behavior.

(2) Override the `Form` formatting of `NavigationLink` so that it's not activated upon tap.

**EDIT:** Seems like option 2 is possible with `.disabled(true)` but the empty section is still visible which is undesirable on top of this seeming a bit hacky.

```
struct FormView  : View {
    @State var showNext: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
               Section {
                   VStack {
                       Text("Hello")

                       NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail View"), isActive: $showNext) 
                       { EmptyView() }
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to hide link into background of some view, like below

```
Form {
 Section {
   VStack {
      Text("Hello")
        .background(
           NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail View"), isActive: $showNext)
             { EmptyView() }.disabled(!showNext)
         )
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Neat trick! Didn't think of this one. Hopefully there's a cleaner way of doing this after the next WWDC.

Comment: Another thing to note: this doesn't seem to work when it's the background of a `Button`. Tapping the button will trigger the button action and the NavigationLink.